# I can't call a Callback method in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, printing

I have a little application with i need to do, in a hardware with some proper libraries. And i'm needing some help with a little call that i need to do. 
This little app is a simple one, he will have a button, with will call a method who will press some little informations, the method that i have to call, i think, is the startPrint, and here follows his documentation:

3.2.10 StartPrint 
Start printing.

public int startPrint (boolean rollPaperEnd, OnPrintListener listener);

Parameters: 
Parameter   Description 
rollPaperEnd - Advance to the end of the paper automatically; true: yes, false: no 
listener - The callback interface after printing is complete

Return Value: 
SdkResult.Success operation is successful; listener can successfully callback 
SdkResult.Printer_Busy printer is busy 
SdkResult.Printer_Print_Fail print data is empty SdkResult.Param_In_Invalid illegal Parameter

---

I still have another methods, like InitPrint and SetLetterSpacing, with i tested and don't do nothing in my application. 
The doubt here is, if you look to the informations in the library, you will see that the method need with two informations are passed the 'boolean rollPaperEnd' and the 'OnPrintListener listener'. The first one is easy, i just pass True, but in the second case i tried to pass a lot of different data and nothing works. The description of the documentation to OnPrintListener for me is:

---

4.1     OnPrintListener

Responsible for managing the printer class callback interface.

---

Even knowing that, i don't know what i pass in there to make with the method work. If someone could help me i would stay quite grateful.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. Take some time, but i thought that would be more difficulty.

I created that solution:

```
    OnPrintListener imprime = new OnPrintListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrintResult(int i) {
            i = 1;
        }
    };

    printer.startPrint(true, imprime);
```

I simply created the object and it work. Thank for each one who thought about help me.